# How to set a properties order?

Tags: java, json, jersey

I created a simple RESTful API service with Jersey, which returns a JSON to user.

But the problem is that JSON is malformed. I want

```
{
  "x" : 1,
  "y" : 2,
  "result" : 3
}
```

But get

```
{
  "x" : 1,
  "result" : 3,
  "y" : 2
}
```

Here is my DTO

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "result")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(propOrder = {"x", "y", "res"})
public class Result {
    private Long x;
    private Long y;
    private Long res;
    // getters/setters ommited
}
```

How can I set the correct order in JSON response?

Comment: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs" http://www.json.org/

Comment: Note that JSON doesn't care about order. This is purely for aesthetics. What are you using to serialize the POJO?

Comment: `@XmlType(propOrder = ...)` is the documented way. Did u try to clean compile? and also try to remove `(name = "result")` and run it and check if it works.

Comment: I removed `(name = "result")` and got the same JSON.

Comment: What have you declared in Jersey which reads JAXB **XML** annotations and produces **JSON**?

Comment: Fasterxml Jackson, `jersey-media-json-jackson`

Comment: I'd look at your configuration. It doesn't seem like the annotations are used at all. See what happens if you play around with them (remove them, add others, etc.)

Comment: It may not be in the order you want, but it certainly isn't malformed and is equal to the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `@XmlType.propOrder` *should* work just like `@JsonPropertyOrder` (as tested by myself, and as mentioned [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JACKSON-90) and [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations), **given** JAXB annotation support is enabled on the provider.

> [barbara - from comment]: Fasterxml Jackson, `jersey-media-json-jackson`

Here are a list of reasons I can think of, why it *wouldn't* work. First keep in mind, the above mentioned module comes with two different providers, `JacksonJsonProvider` and `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`. I hope by the name you can guess which one offered JAXB annotation support.

1. You explicitly registered the `JacksonJsonProvider`
2. You are using classpath scanning, which would register both the providers, and during the request, the `JacksonJsonProvider` is used. Keep in mind classpath scanning and package scanning are different. Classpath scanning could be enabled by using an empty `Application` subclass

   ```
   @ApplicationPath("/api")
   public class AppConfig extends Application {}
   ```
3. You can `jersey-media-moxy` on the classpath, which is the default provider, and unless disabled, will be used over the `jersey-media-json-jackson` provider.

Some note that might be helpful

- If you are using Jersey 2.9+, Just having the `jersey-media-json-jackson:2.9+` on the classpath, should automatically register the `JacksonFeature`, which uses the `JacksonJaxbJsonProvider`. Version 2.8-, you can explicitly register the `JacksonFeature` either in your `ResourceConfig`

  ```
  public class AppConfig extends ResourceConfig {
      public AppConfig() {
          packages("packages.to.scan");
          register(JacksonFeature.class);
      }
  }
  ```

  or if you are using web.xml, set the feature as an init-param for the Jersey servlet

  ```
  <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
      <param.value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
  </init-param>
  ```

Hopefully this provides you will enough information to fix the problem.